# Как измененить размер текста при касании к объекту интерфейса без использования Java?

Tags: android, android-style, android-ui

Здравствуйте!

Скажите, как можно изменить размер текста при прикосновении к элементу (**без использования Java**)?

Для цвета и фона все просто (используя файлы разметки и `<selector>`), а вот как изменить размер текста никак не могу понять.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В ***Android*** начиная с ***API level 21*** появился такой объект как `StateListAnimator`, который позволяет указать анимации, что будут запущены при изменении View.

Соответственно, как пример, изменим размер текста у кнопки, используя только `.xml` файлы разметки. Для этого в папке `res/anim/` проекта создадим `text_size_animation.xml`, который выглядит так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="0"
                android:propertyName="textSize"
                android:valueTo="24sp"
                android:valueType="floatType"/>
        </set>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="0"
                android:propertyName="textSize"
                android:valueTo="12sp"
                android:valueType="floatType"/>
        </set>
    </item>
</selector>
```

После чего установим у кнопки параметр `android:stateListAnimator="@anim/text_size_animation"`.

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:stateListAnimator="@animator/text_size_animation"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

В итоге мы получили кнопку, при нажатии на которую изменяется размер ее текста с `20sp` до `40sp` за 0 милисекунд.

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток, скорее всего данная задача невыполнима без кода. Вам потребуется повесить слушатель на текст, который будет задавать новый textSize.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView someText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        someText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.someText);
        someText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                someText.setTextSize(20);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Первоначально примерно так и реализовал, но получалось слишком громоздко (только в моем случае было onTouch)

Comment: Чтоб убрать громоздкость, можно создать метод, какой нибудь, private void textSize(), внутри него реализовать Ваш замысел, а потом его вызвать в onCreate(). Ну как вариант.